# Fetch File List from google drive Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to fetch file list from google drive using drive sdk provided in play services.

I am using following query provided in Android Demo's by google itself.

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query)
               .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);

/**
     * Gives the result back in MetadataBufferReuslt format
     */
    final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                    ArrayList<GoogleDriveResultModel> googleDriveResultArr=new ArrayList<>();
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        showSnackBar("Problem while retrieving results");
                        return;
                    }
                    googleDriveResultArr.clear();

                    showSnackBar("Found " + result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount() + " files");

                    for(Metadata metadata: result.getMetadataBuffer()){
                            GoogleDriveResultModel model = new GoogleDriveResultModel();
                            model.setTitle(metadata.getTitle());
                            model.setGoogleDriveId(metadata.getDriveId().getResourceId());
                            model.setLink(metadata.getWebContentLink());
                            googleDriveResultArr.add(model);
                        Config.debug("Google File " + metadata.getDriveId().getResourceId() + " : " + metadata.getTitle() +
                                " : " + metadata.getWebContentLink()+" is Trashed "+metadata.isTrashed());
                    }


                }
            };
```

problem here is I am not getting of files that I have added or deleted. It shows same files. I think its not syncing with server. I have tried to see those files through Google Drive app, everything seems fine. Its just my app that is not fetching updated files (i.e added/deleted files) any guess?

Comment: Just to make sure, Are the new files created / deleted by THE SAME Android App? Under the FILE scope, no objects created by other apps (like 'drive.google.com' for instance ) are visible to you 'query()'.

Comment: @seanpj Nope I am adding /deleting files on web in drive and trying to see difference in app.

Comment: So , your code (and mine below) is probably correct. It is the FILE scope that is causing your problem, Unfortunately [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) has only this scope. You have 2 options: use GDAA's file picker, or switch to the  [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Api with DRIVE scope.

Comment: @seanpj can you give some pointers like tuts. I have tried using rest api https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key={API_KEY} I was getting 401 error.

Comment: Start with basic CRUD functionality ([GDAA](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) or [REST](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo)). I can't decide for you which one to use, since I don't know what your goal is.

Comment: @seanpj my goal is to get file list from users drive and extract download link out of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. private static Drive service;

Copy this method and call it :

private void saveFileToDevice() {

```
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                FileList temp = null;
                try {
                    temp = service
                            .files()
                            .list()
                            .execute();
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),
                            REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (temp != null) {
                    if (temp.getItems().size() <= 0) {
                        showToast("No File Available for Download.");
                        DeleteAlbumTask del = new DeleteAlbumTask();
                        del.execute(0);
                        return;
                    }
                    final FileList finalTemp = temp;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showFileSelectList(finalTemp);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    showToast("No File Available for Download.");
                    DeleteAlbumTask del = new DeleteAlbumTask();
                    del.execute(0);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        showToast(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code using google play services sdk? is it for fetching all files from drive sdk. not specific file ?

Comment: It is possible to mix the  [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) and the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro), but you'll run into timing / latency issues you'll have to handle.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Based on our comment exchange above, the solution below probably does not help. The problem is very likely in the visibility scope GDAA supports. See the '[Connecting and Authorizing the Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)' paragraph.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
It would be difficult to figure out why your query's failing if I don't see the query itself.
So, since I can't help you there, I may offer a code snippet you may try to plug in, just to see if you get lucky. You can modify the filter-building section to suit your needs and it has to sit in non-UI thread wrapper like AyncTask, Thread, ...
Parent ID is supplied as a String expression of DriveId. And mGAC is mGoogleApiClient of course.

```
  /****************************************************************************
   * find file/folder in GOODrive
   * @param prnId   parent ID (optional), null searches full drive, "root" searches Drive root
   * @param titl    file/folder name (optional)
   * @param mime    file/folder mime type (optional)
   */
  static void search(String prnId, String titl, String mime) {

    if (mGAC != null && mGAC.isConnected()) try {

      // add query conditions, build query
      ArrayList<Filter> fltrs = new ArrayList<>();
      if (prnId != null){
        fltrs.add(Filters.in(SearchableField.PARENTS, prnId.equalsIgnoreCase("root") ?
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGAC).getDriveId() : DriveId.decodeFromString(prnId)));
      }
      if (titl != null) fltrs.add(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, titl));
      if (mime != null) fltrs.add(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, mime));
      Query qry = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(fltrs)).build();

      // fire the query
      MetadataBufferResult rslt = Drive.DriveApi.query(mGAC, qry).await();
      if (rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        MetadataBuffer mdb = null;
        try {
          mdb = rslt.getMetadataBuffer();
          for (Metadata md : mdb) {
            if (md == null || !md.isDataValid() || md.isTrashed()) continue;
            //   md.getTitle(), md.getDriveId(), ....
          }
        } finally { if (mdb != null) mdb.close(); }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
```

It has worked for me so far, Good Luck